# TinyIOC not registering same types on different debug runs , web api project using Azure emulator

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, tinyioc

This is driving me nuts ...
I have a web API project . I am getting an odd behaviour . I am running it in a debugger and hitting a method by using fiddler . What is happening is that the API works fine on first the first time I run it in debug after a build  . But I get 500s the second time . I have tracked the problem down to TinyIOC being able to autoregister  74 types on the first debug run , and only 13 on the second  .  I am not making any changes . I build , I start debug it works . I stop debug , start debug again and it doesn't.The error is it cannot create my controller , no default constructor , which is caused by TinyIOC not registering the types . But I don't know why . I can only assume that the assemblies that TinyIOC  can see are different on the different runs  . But how ? and why ? I am stumped .

It is a windows azure cloud service , running against IIS express with Azure emulation . . Has anyone come up against this before ?

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone else loses a significant portion of their lives , I am adding this , hopefully if this is nonsense then someone will chime in . It turned out to be that TinyIOC calls AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() . 
But Asp.net was not loading the dlls until needed . So I added a call to     BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(); 
Prior to initialising TinyIOC , which is probably not the best solution but it gets me going.
I'm still not clear on why it worked on the first debug run though.....